# StreamProvider which is nested in StreamProvider stuck on loading

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing

I'm using `recordStreamProvider` as a parent `StreamProvider`, and `userStreamProvider` as a nested `StreamProvider` in my Flutter app. However, the `recordStreamProvider` is getting stuck on the loading state and not updating with new data from the `userStreamProvider`. Some problem may be in `recordStreamProvider` (`userStreamProvider` works.) What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Here is my `repogitories.dart` code:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final userStreamProvider = StreamProvider((_) {
  return FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().map((user) {
    return user;
  });
});

final recordStreamProvider = StreamProvider<List<Record>>((ref) {
  User? user = null;
  // User? user = ref.watch(userStreamProvider).value;
  if (user == null) {
    return Stream.value([]);
  } else {
    CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> cref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('/$usersFieldKey/${user.uid}/$recordsFieldKey');
    return cref.snapshots().map((snapshot) =>
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Record.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
  }
});
```

Here is my `repogitories_test.dart` test code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() async {
  group('recordStreamProvider', () {
    test('returns empty list if user is null', () async {
      // Override the userStreamProvider with a null AsyncValue.
      final container = ProviderContainer(
        overrides: [
          userStreamProvider.overrideWith((ref) => Stream.value(null)),
        ],
      );
      container.refresh(userStreamProvider);
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      final recordStream = container.read(recordStreamProvider);

      // Retrieve the stream provider and evaluate its state.
      expect(recordStream.value, []);
    });
  });
}
```

Expect to get the value of an empty list from `recordStream`, but got the following result by testing:

```
00:03 +0 -1: recordStreamProvider returns empty list if user is null [E]
  Expected: []
    Actual: <null>
     Which: is not Iterable

  package:test_api                       expect
  test\record_repogitory_test.dart 42:7  main.<fn>.<fn>


'recordStreamProvider returns empty list if user is null'
00:03 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
```

Comment: Why are you saying `Stream.value(null)` instead of `Stream.value([])`?

Comment: `Steam.value(null)` is for `UserStreamProvider`. then, `RecordStreamProvider` is getting user by `ref.watch(userStreamProvider).value` (now I noticed and commented out it after trial and error so far...)

Comment: somebody help??